# Different fonts of axis labels in R plots in OSX and Ubuntu

Tags: r, macos, ubuntu, fonts

When I am testing my shiny app on OSX, font of axis labels looks ok, so I know where to cut it to make it short enough to fit the area for the plot.

[image: right font]

but when I'm testing it on our server (running Ubuntu) it has different font and looks like this

[image: wrong font]

code for generating the axis is

```
axis(2, ncol(t(dist_m)):1, rownames(t(dist_m)),las = 2,cex.axis = 0.85,tick = F,font = 1,family = "sans")
```

I was trying to use `library(extrafont)`, but I couldn't make it work on Ubuntu (Mac was ok).

Comment: What is the font used on Mac OS? it might be that the font used on Mac OS is not present on Linux

Comment: If you are responding to part with `library(extrafont)`, I was trying it with different fonts from the list of fonts (from `fonts()`), but neither one of them affected anything (on Ubuntu). Otherwise I was using `family = "sans"` and it looks different - can I set default font for R somehow?
I was also trying _Hershey Vector Fonts_ (HersheySans), but they look awful.